# Retrieving data from Firebase equals unexpected nil - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get the weirdest error and I do not know how to fix it..
I have a Firebase database with all posts made from users. They are stored under `feed-items`. Whenever a user makes a new post, the post is added to `feed-items` and the key of the post in feed-items (an autoId) is added to every follower that the user has.

If I show all posts from `feed-items` in my UITableView then there is no problem at all. If I try to show posts that are equal to the keys stored in the users personal wall (the key that was added when users that I am following makes a post), then I get a weird error saying `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional` in my `Sweet` struct?

Let me first show you the two codes, one working the other is not:

**WORKING CODE:**

```
func observePosts(userID: String) {
//        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Wall")
//        ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
//            
//            let postId = snapshot.key
            let postReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items")//.child(postId)

            postReference.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
                var newUpdates = [Sweet]()
                    for update in snapshot.children {
                        let postUpdates = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                        newUpdates.append(postUpdates)
                    }
                    self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }, withCancelBlock: nil)
            //}, withCancelBlock: nil)
    }
```

**NOT WORKING CODE:**

```
func observePosts(userID: String) {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Wall")
        ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            let postId = snapshot.key
            let postReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(postId)

            postReference.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
                var newUpdates = [Sweet]()
                    for update in snapshot.children {
                        let postUpdates = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                        newUpdates.append(postUpdates)
                    }

                    self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }, withCancelBlock: nil)
            }, withCancelBlock: nil)
    }
```

Where the app crashes and the line I get the error is in my struct, under likesForPost

**MY STRUCT**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import UIKit

struct Sweet {
    let key: String!
    let content: String!
    let addedByUser: String!
    let profilePhoto: String!
    var likesForPost : [String:AnyObject]
    let itemRef: FIRDatabaseReference?
    let path : String!
    let date: String!
    let category: Int!
    let workoutComment: String!
    let workoutTime: String!


    init (content: String, addedByUser: String, profilePhoto: String!, likesForPost : [String:AnyObject]!, date: String, category: Int, workoutComment: String, workoutTime: String, key: String = "") {
        self.key = key
        self.content = content
        self.addedByUser = addedByUser
        self.profilePhoto = profilePhoto
        self.likesForPost = likesForPost
        self.itemRef = nil
        // self.path = dataPath
        self.path = ""
        self.date = date
        self.category = category
        self.Comment = Comment
        self.Time = Time
    }

    init (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        itemRef = snapshot.ref
        path  = key
        if let theFeedContent = snapshot.value!["content"] as? String {
            content = theFeedContent
        } else {
            content = ""
        }

        if let feedUser = snapshot.value!["addedByUser"] as? String {
            addedByUser = feedUser
        } else {
            addedByUser = ""
        }

        if let feedPhoto = snapshot.value!["profilePhoto"] as? String! {
            profilePhoto = feedPhoto
        } else {
            profilePhoto = ""
        }

        if let feedLikes = snapshot.value!["likesForPost"] as? [String:AnyObject]! {
            likesForPost = feedLikes
        } else {
            likesForPost = ["":""]
        }

        if let feedDate = snapshot.value!["date"] as? String! {
            date = feedDate
        } else {
            date = ""
        }

        if let feedCategory = snapshot.value!["category"] as? Int! {
            category = feedCategory
        } else {
            category = 0
        }

        if let feedComment = snapshot.value!["Comment"] as? String! {
            Comment = feedComment
        } else {
            Comment = ""
        }

        if let feedTime = snapshot.value!["Time"] as? String! {
            Time = feedTime
        } else {
            Time = ""
        }

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
        return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser, "profilePhoto":profilePhoto!, "likesForPost":likesForPost, "date":date, "category":category, "Comment":Comment, "Time":Time]
    }
}
```

I know it is a long post but I would be so happy if you took the time to help me - I am completely lost! :(

**EDIT:**
This is what the log is giving me:

```
Snap (-KXLGyWMljc2UNeRL1a3) {
    addedByUser = "Maja P";
    category = 1;
    content = Hejehjehj;
    date = "Nov,24,,2016,,1:20";
    likesForPost =     {
        "user id" = 0;
    };
    profilePhoto = VGpbOweP4jO2seeLNCGiv1p08jq1;
    Comment = "";
    Time = "";
}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Which is completely correct, but there are two posts where it is only printing the one above.

Comment: All of the `!` in your struct are potential issues.  Do you need to use implicitly unwrapped optionals?  Dereferencing any one of those could cause the crash if they're `nil`.

Comment: None of them should be nil that is what I do not understand - and as you can see in the bottom of my question, the output none of the values are nil? @sbooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in the second code you are directly getting `DataSnapshot` of your Post, I don't think you need to iterate the `snapshot`.

Try changing your code to this, see if it works.

```
func observePosts(userID: String) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Wall")
    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        let postId = snapshot.key
        let postReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(postId)

        postReference.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
                let update = Sweet(snapshot: snapshot)
                self.updates.insert(update, atIndex: 0)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }, withCancelBlock: nil)

        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I have been looking for this for so long! Thank you so much :-) Do you have any idea of how I can reverse the `self.updates`? If I do `self.updates.reverse()` it says it is unused and nothing happens :(

Comment: I guess you are using Swift 2, in that case write `self.updates = self.updates.reverse()` to reverse your array.

Comment: Works like a charm!